# Colon at end of section directive causes segfault

Tags: nasm

It's a semi-common error for me to accidentally include a colon (`:`) at the end of a `section` directive:

```
section .text:
    _start:
```

When done to the `.text` section, this causes a `SIGSEGV` before the first instruction can be executed though, and I'm curious as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maintenance info sections` in GDB shows what's going on.

Without a colon:

```
gef➤  maintenance info sections 
Exec file:
    `my/path', file type elf64-x86-64.
 [0]     0x00401000->0x00401005 at 0x00001000: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
```

With a colon:

```
gef➤  maintenance info sections 
Exec file:
    `my/path', file type elf64-x86-64.
 [0]     0x00401000->0x00401005 at 0x00001000: .text: ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
```

`.text ... CODE` vs `.text: ... DATA`.

So, it seems like the colon is taken as literally part of the section name. As a result, it isn't considered to be the `.text` section, and isn't marked as executable.